# Couldn't find Job with 'id'=3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you create new job, you'll get redirected to show page (/jobs/[:id]). But, when you try to reload a page or edit a job, you'll get an error in the title. There is set_job, which is set properly as far as I see and that is marked as an error.

Here's a controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.published.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save            
        format.html { redirect_to @job }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private

    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:name, :description, :image, :location, :deleted, :user_id, :tag_list)
    end

end
```

logs:

```
Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]                                                                                         
Completed 404 Not Found in 74ms                                                                                                                                                       

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job with 'id'=3):                                                                                                                         
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:56:in `set_job'
```

logs part 2

```
Started POST "/jobs" for 188.246.77.192 at 2014-09-20 22:11:03 +0000                                                                                                                  
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML                                                                                                                                           
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8gO/Q8ktERzKdMzDtB8KEU6CH8oIayNAb2AZhUzL2d0=", "job"=>{"name"=>"My first job", "description"=>"test", "tag_list"=>"rails, programmi
ng", "location"=>"Red River, United States", "user_id"=>"1"}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "commit"=>"Submit"}                                                                             
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                        
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                     
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = '2014-09-20 22:11:03.154670', "last_seen_at" = '2014-09-20 22:11:03.154670' WHERE "users"."id" = 1                                   
   (4.3ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                    
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                     
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]                                                                                     
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"  WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = $1 AND ("jobs"."created_at" BETWEEN '2014-09-20 00:00:00.000000' AND '2014-09-20 22:11:03.168092')  [["user_id", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("created_at", "description", "location", "name", "tag_list", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["create
d_at", "2014-09-20 22:11:03.170612"], ["description", "test"], ["location", "Red River, United States"], ["name", "My first job"], ["tag_list", "rails, programming"], ["updated_at", 
"2014-09-20 22:11:03.170612"], ["user_id", 1]]                                                                                                                                        
   (3.0ms)  COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                    
Redirected to http://example.com/jobs/3                                                                                                                
Completed 302 Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

Comment: I think you should first check that a job with id =3 exist. Go to your terminal, navigate inside your application and run:

    rails c

Then run the following to check if the job with id 3 exist:

    Job.find(3)

Comment: It doesn't exist. Weird. When I created a record, I was redirected to a show page. Now, when I create a new record, it is #4. What do you think is going on?

Comment: And is this record 4  actually getting stored in the table? Check as you checked for record 3.If no, then probably there is a problem in create action. In that case can you print the params for create action and put them here.

Comment: I've updated the post. What could be a problem with create action? After create, I am being redirected to show page, but when I try to reload it, it says record doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Job**

The bottom line is that you'll not have a `Job` in your database with an `id` of `3` - the way to fixing it will come from determining *why* this does get populated.

Specifically, that you'll either have a problem with the `save` method or your `database`. Here's what I would do to resolve it:

```
#app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
class JobsController < AppicationController
   def new
      @job = Job.new
   end

   def create
      @job = Job.new job_params
      @job.save
   end

   private

   def job_params
      require(:job).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

You already have the controller right - the problem with therefore likely be with the way this data is being saved in your database. This will either be a problem with your `model`, or your `save` mechanism itself.

Here's what your model should look like:

```
#app/models/job.rb
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rn
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :jobs
end
```

This will ensure your models are not causing an issue. There might be another issue in respect to the `validations` you have - you should **comment out any of the validations** in your `Job` model, just to check if it submits correctly

--

**DB**

You should further ensure that you have the correct `db` set up for your `Job` `model`

To do this, you need to ensure you have done the following:

> $ rake db:migrate

This is of course if you have created the correct migrations previously for your model!

---

Finally, you'll be able to check the presence of the `job` record in your db using the `rails console`:

```
> $ rails c
> $ jobs = Job.all
> # -> all jobs outputted
```

From this, you'll be able to see where your records have been inserted, thus allowing you to see what's happened to the records you've saved